# tensorflow - map_fn - global variable access

Tags: tensorflow, global

Could you tell me the right way to return from the above function with return statement :  return z[key] ?

```
from IPython import display
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import argparse
import sys

global z
z = np.arange(400, 420 + 1)

def try_mapping(key):
    # print(key)
    # print(key.dtype)
    #return key*2
    return z[key]

def inputs(data):
    keys = tf.map_fn(try_mapping , data)
    return keys

def main(unused_argv):
    x = np.arange(1, 20 + 1)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Key': x})
    keys  = inputs(df)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print(sess.run(keys))
```